# Joomla 2.5 & sigPlus & BoxPlus: Add Animation

Tags: joomla, mootools, gallery, joomla2.5, transition

I'm working on a joomla 2.5 website and I'm using the [sigPlus plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/content-photo-gallery/11426) to display an image gallery. The gallery is displayed using the boxplus popup engine.

All works fine but I would like to add transitions between the images instead of showing the loading indicator. Boxplus uses mootools - does anyone know how to easily add transitions?

Btw: I can not use the boxplus slider engine unfortunately (this one would have transitions built in already)

Many thanks

Comment: by transitions you mean a fade in/out between images? do you have a fiddle or a link?

Comment: yes - my question is really sigplus specific. I want to fade out the previous picture while it's on top of the new one

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle with the plugin so we can help from there.

Comment: I don't think the license of sigplus allows me to do that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Mootools has built in transitions.

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Transitions

Comment: Thanks for the link. I realize that the wording of my question is misleading. It is very specific to how the sigplus plugin is structured. The current and next image are not loaded at the same time in the current version which makes it difficult to use any kind of transition.

Comment: Ah, in that case there is no easy solution. You are going to have to change how sigPlus works at the core to preload the images in order to use transitions. Changing the core code like this will make it impossible to update so you are better off recreating the extension with a new name so you don't lose your edits.